# Remove characters mid STRING

Tags: hive, character

My column has the following data: (This is an example, the real one has 1 million rows)

**Input:**

```
NumberID
17.843.983-9
8.365.938-1
10.294.487-5
```

I need to delete both '.' from the string. Expected column:

**Expected Output:**

```
NumberID
17843983-9
8365938-1
10294487-5
```

I tried with substr and regexp replace, but I cant seem to find the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

```
hive> with t as (select stack(3,'17.843.983-9','8.365.938-1','10.294.487-5') as col)
    > select  regexp_replace(col,'\\.','')
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
_c0
17843983-9
8365938-1
10294487-5
```

or

```
hive> with t as (select stack(3,'17.843.983-9','8.365.938-1','10.294.487-5') as col)
    > select  replace(col,'.','')
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
_c0
17843983-9
8365938-1
10294487-5
```